# Adding Game Center Support on iTunesConnect Broke My In App Purchasing

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, game-center

I had a well functioning in app purchase system in place and everything was going great. However, after managing Game Center and adding some leaderboards/achievements here on iTunes Connect (without changing anything in the code), in app purchase stopped working altogether and keeps giving me "Unable to Connect" errors. Could this have somehow messed up the sandbox environment? Anyone know what could be the problem?

I think there is a definite correlation since enabling/disabling Game Center on iTunesConnect changes behaviour on the device, but even if I disable everything it tsill won't go back to the way it was before).

I've been at this for days now. Help?

Answer (score -2):

I doubt there's any correlation between Game Center and IAP, although the sandboxes are pretty unreliable. Have you checked so that your Paid Applications contract hasn't expired or is invalid in some other way? Also, have you checked that your test user is still valid?